# Fabric js bounding box positioning issue

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Bounding box for some custom path is not positioned correctly. I am using fabricjs library please help me how to remove this bug. I am using the following code to generate the path.

```
var path = new fabric.Path('m138.31999,1l0,29.565c-75.13835,4.16908 -134.31995,48.17229 -134.31999,101.835c0,-9.67107 16.35202,-17.51999 36.5,-17.51999c20.14798,0 36.5,7.84892 36.5,17.51999c0,-9.67107 16.35202,-17.51999 36.5,-17.51999c9.59525,0 18.30284,1.83565 24.81999,4.745l0,144.17499c0,6.44742 -5.23262,11.68002 -11.67999,11.68002c-6.44734,0 -11.68,-5.2326 -11.68,-11.68002l0,-5.84l-23.36,0l0,5.84c0,19.34207 15.6979,35.04001 35.04,35.04001c19.34206,0 35.04001,-15.69794 35.04001,-35.04001l0,-144.17499c6.51714,-2.90935 15.22475,-4.745 24.81999,-4.745c20.14798,0 36.5,7.84892 36.5,17.51999c0,-9.67107 16.35202,-17.51999 36.5,-17.51999c20.14798,0 36.5,7.84892 36.5,17.51999c0,-53.66274 -59.18159,-97.66592 -134.31999,-101.835l0,-29.565l-23.36002,0z');
canvas.add(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the bounding box to your object corner with this code:

```
path.pathOffset.x = 0;
path.pathOffset.y = 0;
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to resize it automatically. You can change bounding box size by `path.width` and `path.height` properties but it seems that Fabric will not compute it for you. Maybe you'll need to iterate over path `points` array to find min/max values for X and Y, so you can compute the BB size on your own.

Comment: `path.class.js` has private method `_parseDimensions` with the similar function, that returns object with calculated fields `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` based on the path commands. However, `left` and `top` are actually coordinates of the center rather than the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug of the library with some beizer and arcs. Now, since `1.5.0`, every known path is handled correctly.